# detect specific strings with or without spaces in between in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-group

I want to write a javascript regex to detect 3 specific set of characters:

1. the string 'className'
2. the character '='
3. the character '{'

And I want to detect these with or without spaces - meaning it should work for all these strings:

```
'className={}'
'className ={}'
'className= {'
'className = {}'
```

How can we detect specific groups of exact characters with or without spaces in regex??

Comment: /^className\s*=\s*{/ you can try this

Comment: Thanks a lot - it works - duly noted the use of * character in this!! Awesome!

Comment: and I also forgot to mention a  case where this pattern is in the middle of something else - so I removed the caret at the beginning

Comment: You should use `\b` word boundaries instead of caret in such case. else it will detect thing like `helloclassName={` too

Answer (score 0):

Check for one or more spaces between each required character set:

```js
const strings = ['className={}',
  'className ={}',
  'className= {',
  'className = {}'
];

const regex = /className\s*=\s*\{\}\s*/;
strings.forEach(str => console.log(regex.test(str)));
```

<sub>Note: The third example returns false because there is no closing curly brace `}`.</sub>

If the last brace is optional:

```js
const strings = ['className={}',
  'className ={}',
  'className= {',
  'className = {}'
];

const regex = /className\s*=\s*\{\}?\s*/;
strings.forEach(str => console.log(regex.test(str)));
```

Comment: Thanks - this works - actually I don't need the end curly brace -

Comment: So you want the last brace to be optional @Probosckie?

Comment: yes - so I'm using let classNameRegex = /className\s*=\s*{/;